# How do I stop Melody's terrible music?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I like playing as Melody but I can't stand her music. I know it's possible to use custom songs, but I really like Cadance and Aria's music.

Is there a way to set Melody to use the default music or, better still, Aria's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 soundtracks in the game (named after composer/remixer):

- **Danny B** for Cadence
- **A-Rival** for Melody
- **FamilyJules7x** for Aria
- Other characters use Danny B

That is, these are the soundtracks by default.
You can changes these to whatever you want in the *Pause menu* => *Options* => *Change soundtrack*. The soundtrack option is selectable on character by character bases and the latest patch even introduced a new option, *Random*.

To get what you want, navigate to *Change soundtrack* and change Melody's soundtrack to either **Danny B** or **FamilyJules7x**.

Also, there are Steam Workshop mod that can change the soundtrack even futher. For example, here's one that replaces Danny B's sountrack with a remix that combines all three: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=431443857